# Ajax forms  - what if broswer doesn't support javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I know some PHP and now I want to combine it using ajax/jquery. Just for learning purpose im making some scripts. I wanted to make a register form that checks availability etc etc. But before I start to make such a script i'd wanted to do something easier just to check how it works.

My goal was a contact form with ajax and it works. Data gets sended to php validate script. Errors are saved in an array and it returns a list of errors or sends the message.

But I have a few questions:

1. What if a browser doesnt support javascript. Is there a way to still send the message?
2. the submit triggers the ajax post function. what is the best way to add jquery validation before it goes to the php file (client side)

   Contact AJAX Form

   ```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
       function ajax_post(){
           // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
           var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
           var url = "functions/validation.php";
           var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
           var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
           var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
           var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
           var vars = "name="+name+"&subject="+subject+"&email="+email+"&message="+message;
           hr.open("POST", url, true);
           // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
           hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
           hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                   var return_data = hr.responseText;
                   document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
               }
           }
           // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
           hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
           document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";

       }
   </script>
   ```

   ## Contact form

   text

   ```
       <label>Name
           <span id="nameInfo" class="small">Add your name</span>
       </label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

       <label>subject
           <span id="subjectInfo" class="small">Add a subject</span>
       </label>
       <input type="text" name="email" id="subject" />

       <label>Email
           <span id="emailInfo" class="small">Add a valid email address</span>
       </label>
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

       <label>message
           <span id="messageInfo" class="small">Your message min 20 chars</span>
       </label>
       <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />

       <button type="submit" onClick="javascript:ajax_post();">Send</button>
       <div class="spacer"></div>
       <div id="status"></div>
   ```

Comment: FYI, your code breaks as soon as someone enters e.g. a `&` in one of the fields. It also breaks in older IE versions that do not have the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Consider using jQuery or a similar library and let it handle all the AJAX things.

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ is worth a look, too. It turns AJAX form submission into a one-liner. If you have any questions about it, please **do not** edit this question but post a new one instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if a browser doesnt support javascript. Is there a way to still send the message?

If you built it properly it the form will submit the data normally if JavaScript isn't available in the client. [Progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) and should always be how JavaScript is used.

> the submit triggers the ajax post function. what is the best way to add jquery validation before it goes to the php file (client side)

Use the [`submit` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to capture the form data before submission.

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript is not available the form will be submitted in the classic way. Your server-side code needs to handle this and return a full HTML page in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using jquery?
Just have a `<form>` tag send the data and disable/return false at the submit() event of said form.